# Send HTML table through PHPmailer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a dynamic HTML table with PHPmailer but i don't know how, is posible get a variable with all table? or something like that ?

Here is my code:

```
require("inc/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From     = ('compras.co@kantarworldpanel.com');
$mail->FromName = ('Compras CO (KWBTA)');
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['providermail']);
$mail->AddCC("camilo.uribe@kantarworldpanel.com.co");    
$mail->IsHTML(true);        


 //IF SUBMIT, SEND MAIL 
 if (isset ($_POST['send_approve'])) {
$mail->Subject = "Kantar Worldpanel - Solicitud de Cotización";
$contenido =  'Kantar Worldpanel  Perú S.A. Sucursal Colombia desea solicitar a ustedes la cotización correspondiente a los siguientes Items:<br>';

////////////////////////////////////////////
$contenido .= ' The Table should be here;
///////////////////////////////////////////

$mail->Body    = $contenido;
$mail->Send();
header ("Location: RequestsPA.php");
}
```

And here is the table code:

```
<?php 
$sqlStr = "SELECT items.CA_id, items.item_id, items.item_Cant, items.CECO_cod, items.item_desc, items.item_enduser
FROM items where CA_id = ".$CA_id;
$sqlStrAux = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM items";

$aux = Mysql_Fetch_Assoc(mysql_query($sqlStrAux));
$query = mysql_query($sqlStr);  

if($aux['total']>0){

    echo "</br></br>";
    echo "<div class='datagrid'>";
    echo "\t<table class=\"tablesorter\">\n";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>CECO</th>
        <th>Descripción de solicitud</th>
        <th>Usuario final</th>          
      </tr>\n";
    echo "</thead>";      
        echo "<tbody>";
        $r=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "\t\t<tr class=\"row$r\">
            <td>".htmlentities($row['item_id'])."</td>
            <td>".htmlentities($row['item_Cant'])."</td>
            <td>".htmlentities($row['CECO_cod'])."</td>
            <td>".$row['item_desc']."</td>
            <td>".$row['item_enduser']."</td>
                </tr>\n";
      if($r%2==0)++$r;else--$r;
    }
    echo "</tbody>";                  
    echo "\t</table>\n";
    }
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

I hope you can understand me, thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to send the table or variables inside the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use echo to output your table and capture it with [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), but generally it's easier to assemble the message body in a string, like this:

```
$contenido = '';
if($aux['total']>0){

    $contenido .= "</br></br>";
    $contenido .= "<div class='datagrid'>";
    $contenido .= "\t<table class=\"tablesorter\">\n";
    $contenido .= "<thead>";
    ...
```

Then just use that string as your message body. If you use the same code to generate web page output as your email content then turn that script into a function you can call from either place.

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();

echo 'all my lines of code';

$contenido = ob_get_clean();
```

The above will capture everything between the first and last lines.