# Show table formmat in php email

Tags: php, html-table, phpmailer

```
$m = new PHPMailer();

$boxName = $_POST['name'];
$boxNumber = $_POST['cash'];
$boxSize = $_POST['size'];

$m->Body = '<ol>';
foreach ($boxName as $named)
{
    $m->Body .= "<li>" . $named . "</li>";
}

$m->Body .= "</ol>";
```

how do i make my array data show like a form in email ?
myarray

name

```
 [name] => Array ( [0] => Chris [1] => Yum [2] => mudo [3] => earthlink
```

cash

```
 [cash] => Array ( [0] => 200 [1] => 440 [2] => 110 [3] => 50
```

size

```
   [size] => Array ( [0] => Small [1] => Large [2] => Small [3] => Small
```

how do i make it show in email like this ?

```
 Name        Cash   Size
1.chris      200    Small
2.Yum        440    Small
3.mudo       110    Large
4.earthlink  50     Small
```

Comment: By making a table instead of a list?

Comment: write the appropriate html?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789989/add-html-formatting-in-phpmailer

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922459/send-html-table-through-phpmailer

Comment: You really need to grasp the basics of HTML and PHP and how loops work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send HTML in an email you can do so with:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

More info: [Add HTML formatting in phpmailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789989/add-html-formatting-in-phpmailer)

To have it formatted the way you showed above, use a table.

Comment: doesn't fully answer the question. The question is mostly about having it in an HTML formatted table.

Comment: Given the code above, there's no way for me to write the table code since I don't have all the variables.

Comment: True, yet I doubt we'll be seeing a green tick here. You most likely will be asked questions from the OP, so do be ready for it ;-)